# Unable to execute dex:Multiple dex files define

Tags: android

When build android project , I get the following error. I want to use jdbc driver to connect sql server.

```
[2014-12-02 10:17:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
[2014-12-02 10:17:40 - SQL_WCF] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to order and export tab possibly it should like this :

[image]

Make sure :

- jar in order and export are checked.
- dont add multiple or duplicate lib.